# unable to parse whitespace in regex

Tags: regex

I would like to extract the date string using regex from the following string - `"Mon Feb 25 02:42:27 +0000 2013"`

So given a regex `"\d{3} \s \d{3} \s \d{1,2}"` and string `"Mon Feb 25 02:42:27 +0000 2013"` it should return `"Mon Feb 25"`.

I know I am doing something wrong in expressing white space, can anyone spot it ? ( I am using java)

Comment: use `\w` for white scapes \d for digit use [a-z] instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're using `\d` for alpha characters.  It's for digits.
2. You're putting unnecessary spaces in. They count as literals.

Here's one that would work in .NET:

```
 \w{3}\s\w{3}\s\d{0,2}
```

Comment: How do we know this is in Java?

Comment: Thanks Ann, that did the job !

Comment: Ann I want to extract the string "Feb 25 2013" instead of the day (Mon). How do I extract it ?

Comment: @murtaza52 The answer would take up too much space for me to put it in a comment.  Why don't you ask it as a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say `\d{3}` when you want to parse a word like `Mon`?  Isn't the "d" for "digit"?