# regex to skip intermediate characters

Tags: regex

Given the following string `"Mon Feb 01 02:42:27 +0000 2013"`, what should the regex be to get the following "Feb 01 2013".

The following regex `"\w{3}\s\w{3}\s\d{1,2}"` will yield `"Mon Feb 01"`. How do I write a regex to ignore the day (Mon) and the time and secs ?

I had asked a related question in an earlier post, which was kindly answered by the community - [unable to parse whitespace in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175768/unable-to-parse-whitespace-in-regex/15175794#15175794)

Comment: The string is quite well-formatted. It should be parsable with Date facility in your language (unless you are doing replacement with your text editor)..

Answer (score 0):

This could work :

```
(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun) [a-zA-Z]{3} ([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2}) \+([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{4})
```

Comment: Thanks, this yields ["Mon Feb 01 02:42:27 +0000 2013"
 "Mon"
 "01"
 "02"
 "42"
 "27"
 "0000"
 "2013"].